# Omniture Site Catalyst eVars and Props interchangable

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

I am studying Omniture/Site Catalyst on my own and have the following query:

- Scenario where eVars can be used as a props variable.
- Scenario where props can be used as a eVars variable.

I have a basic understanding of eVars and Props and as per my thinking the 2nd scenario is invalid and we can't use props in place of eVars.

Is there any scenario where eVars can be used as a props variable.

Answer (score 1):

Props and eVars are only really interchangeable if you're looking to only record the actual value of something. They are pretty much different and not interchangeable in most other aspects.

One major thing a prop can do that an eVar can't is that you can enable pathing on a prop but not an eVar. But also, they have a handful of mutually exclusive items they can be correlated/broken down with, as well as some mutually exclusive available metrics.

Also, one or the other may be better for segmenting, depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Here is a link that gives more details:

http://helpx.adobe.com/analytics/kb/compare-props-evars.html

One thing to note that is out of date on that page is that you can now enable pathing on a prop yourself.

Answer (score 1):

- Scenario where eVars can be used as a props variable-When you expire evar on hit then it act as prop
- Scenario where props can be used as a eVars variable-Only when you are interested to know Instances

Answer (score 0):

Props have one value per page, eVars have one value per session [1]. You use props when you want to see how a value changes from page to page (pathing), you use eVars when you are interested in the value that was set last in the session (i.e. to identify an internal campaign).

Plus, what Crayon Violent said.

[1] Actually you can set different conditions at which eVars expire, so they might have different values in one session. Still, usually a new value overwrites the previous one in en eVars (hence no pathing for eVars).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it from a reporting aspect is props will tell you where users are going while eVars also let you know where they're coming from.  We'll set an eVar on a directory page and not on the detail page - in the reports, though, you'll see that eVar against those detail pages...which can tell you which directory page (or other) the user came from (or...converted from, hence the idea of a conversion variable).  The synonymous prop on the other hand only records visits to that directory page (just a traffic variable).